# modern Mac/iOS equivalent of FillParseTable?

Tags: cocoa, text, encoding, core-foundation

I'm updating some older code that works with a variety of older (pre-Unicode) text encodings.  These encodings generally have certain bytes that indicate the start of a two-byte character, while others (usually the ASCII set) represent a character with just one byte.

On the Mac, the old code uses the FillParseTable API (from Script.h) to get a table of which bytes indicate the start of a two-byte character.  But that API has been deprecated a while, and is going away entirely soon.  So we need to replace it with something else.  The header says "Please use the combination of CFString, UCGetCharProperty and CFCharacterSet instead."

But I can't figure out how any combination of those things does what FillParseTable does.  I'm looking at a byte stream in MacJapanese, I see 0x93; is that a character in itself, or the start of a two-byte character?  In fact it's the latter, but I don't see how CoreFoundation (or Cocoa) can tell me that.

Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: Do you need to walk the character array yourself, or can you create a CFString from the character buffer and walk the code points that it interprets for you? Knowing a little bit more about what you're trying to do, rather than just how you want to do it, would probably help others answer the question.

Comment: To maintain the existing behavior, I really need to walk the character array myself.  Without going into too much of the why-fors, the code allows users to manipulate text in these legacy encodings in various ways, including both as bytes and as text.  If I just convert everything to a CFString, the behavior is sure to change, and users get upset.